# Not able to install packages MicrosoftML and mrsdeploy in R studio

Tags: r

I am trying to deploy R code onto server. But for I think we need to install both `MicrosoftML` and `mrsdeploy`. But I get an error while trying to download:

```
install.packages("MicrosoftML")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/vinay/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
```

> package ‘MicrosoftML’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)

```
install.packages("mrsdeploy")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/vinay/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
```

> package ‘mrsdeploy’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

As the above error suggest you that the packages `MicrosoftML` and `mrsdeploy` are not available in `R version 3.5.2`, so you will have to use the `R version` in which these packages are present/compatible.

You can refer to this issue:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/352

For `MicrosoftML` refer to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/machine-learning-server/r/concept-what-is-the-microsoftml-package

Comment: I agree with this. But only because of this, I need to install again R with that compatible version

Comment: Yes, you will have to install that specific version of R which is compatible with the packages `MicrosoftML` and `mrsdeploy`, else you can create a virtual env with the specific version of R installed.

Comment: Oh thats good. Can you please guide me on how to create virtual env with the specific version

Comment: Just replicate your system env using virtual box https://www.wikihow.com/Install-VirtualBox and https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and install R specific version on this virtual machine.

Comment: thanks. Will try. one question. Can I also install R on Amazon virtual machine or AWS?

Comment: If you have ec2 instance of AWS follow this post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an R Client deployment to have the ability to use the RevoScaleR, MicrosoftML, and mrsdeploy packages. Specifically for R version 3.5.2 and Ubuntu 14.04 - 16.04, please follow the following steps:

```
# Install as root or sudo
sudo su

# If your system does not have the https apt transport option, add it now
apt-get install apt-transport-https

# Set the package repository location containing the R Client distribution. 
# On Ubuntu 14.04.
# wget http://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/14.04/prod/packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
# On Ubuntu 16.04.
wget http://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb 

# Register the repo.
dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Check for microsoft-prod.list configuration file to verify registration.
ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

# Update packages on your system
apt-get update

# Install the 3.5.2 packages
# Alternative for 3.4.1: apt-get install microsoft-r-client-packages-3.4.1
# Alternative for 3.4.3: apt-get install microsoft-r-client-packages-3.4.3
apt-get install microsoft-r-client-packages-3.5.2

# List the packages
ls /opt/microsoft/rclient/
```

Then download one of:

Ubuntu 14.04:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/14.04/prod/pool/main/m/microsoft-r-client-packages-3.5.2/microsoft-r-client-packages-3.5.2.deb
```

Ubuntu 16.04:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/pool/main/m/microsoft-r-client-packages-3.5.2/microsoft-r-client-packages-3.5.2.deb
```

Install the packages with:

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

If you use RStudio you can on Linux add `R_LIBS_SITE=/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.5.2/libraries/RServer` on bottom of the file `/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.5.2/runtime/R/etc/Renviron`

Both packages mrsdeploy and MicrosoftML will be now available from RStudio as you can check with:

```
library(mrsdeploy)
library(MicrosoftML)
```

For instructions like the above for newer R versions please [check this Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-client/install-on-linux).